# IE 9 Displaying "Permission Denied" Error on Google GeoChart

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using Google's GeoChart to display some activity data I've gathered from an outside source. It works fine on Firefox and Chrome but IE keeps displaying these "Permission Denied" blocks.

[image: Google's GeoChart showing multiple "Permission Denied" errors on IE9]

Like I said the data is from an outside source and by the time I'm generating the map the data has already been gathered so I don't believe that is contributing to the issue.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'City');
data.addColumn('number', 'Visitors');
data.addRows(dataRows);

var options = {
    region: 'US',
    displayMode: 'markers',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    colorAxis: { colors: ['1A75BB', '1A75BB'] }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('map_3248949334'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

As you can see from the image data points are being mapped in spite of these errors so I'd be happy with a solution that just hides the notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright after some testing I was able to come up with some answers.

I believe the errors are caused by the fact that I am allowing users to redraw the map with different data before the prior map has completed. As the prior request responses continue to roll in errors are thrown. Why this only happens in IE is unclear. I was unable to find any reliable information on how to abort the prior request but I was able to figure out how to hide the error messages.

```
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('map_3248949334'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "error", function errorHandler(e) {
    google.visualization.errors.removeError(e.id);
});
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Hope this helps anyone who runs into a similar issue. :)